# SSRS data-driven subscription file share export: error on one export, others work fine

Tags: reporting-services, subscription, fileshare, data-driven

I have a report with a data-driven subscription that exports Excel files to a file share each day, one per region.  (Region is a parameter in the report.)  The data for the subscription comes from a configuration table that is populated with the list of regions for a given day by another process.  That process takes the Region values from the same table/field that the report query uses to match to the subscription region name in its WHERE clause, so the values should be identical.

The process runs fine but the Executions table shows only two executions (with the correct parameters from the config table), and only two of three exports are generated.  Subscriptions.LastStatus = '**Done: 3 processed of 3 total; 1 errors.**'

- The other two exports are generated correctly, so it's not a
  permissions issue.
- Reports for all three regions export from the
  web portal to excel just fine, so it would seem there's nothing
  preventing an export for that one region.
- There are no differences in the web-portal-exported reports between the 'Central Office' region and
  the 'Rocky Mountain' region that I can see (other than the data,
  obviously).  Both have a space in the name, both have the same number of pages.

I do not have access to the Report Server logs.  I have requested permissions to be able to view the logs, but that's going to take a while.

In the interim, can anyone think of anything else I could try or check?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could just be an issue with the report. Export can't happen if the report errors out.

Comment: if you know you have 3 different parameter values, run the report manually for those three values and see if it errors on one of those and you have to figure out why. We have nothing else to go on to help any more!